# i18n nesting in SAPUI5

Tags: internationalization, sapui5

I have a lot of repeating texts inside of my SAPUI5-App. Hence I have the same value with different keys in i18n.
I don't want to merge them into one key because of readability.
one example:

```
PROFILE_CHAPTER_A=Details
GREET_MESSAGE=Greetings
[...]
WIZARDSTEP_A=Something
WIZARDSTEP_B=Different
WIZARDSTEP_C=In
WIZARDSTEP_D=These
WIZARDSTEP_E=Ones
WIZARDSTEP_F=Details
[...]
#I wish for something like this
GREETING_FORUM={GREET_MESSAGE} {0}, Hello in our Forum!
GREETING_ WEBSOP={GREET_MESSAGE} {0}, Welcome to our Webshop!
```

You see that `PROFILE_CHAPTER_A` and `WIZARDSTEP_F` have the sam value.
In this case I don't want to reference to only one of them because if I'm inside of the view I want a clear naming of the i18n. But if I mean the exact same thing I want to change it only once and not in 5 different keys.

An example of what I imagine should be possible. Maybe I just want to change the "Greetings" to "What's up" or something else and then I just want to reference the first word and have it used by everything else.
Is this i18n-nesting possible in (SAP)UI5? And if not, can it be added?

Comment: Instead of naming features ("wizard step" is a feature) you can also go for a more functional approach to i18n `DETAIL=Detail title` or something.

Comment: @Jorg Yeah of course I could use a new naming scheme but I just got into to the project and can't just change the whole i18n file. That is why I asked, if nesting is available in SAPUI5 i18n. When it is not, the question is, if they implement it or if we have to change our layout. Nevertheless, thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 0):

We use the namespace concept for i18n files:

```
# Global used
core.detail = Detail
core.button.ok = Ok

# Assuming there is a view with namespace: my.great.app.detail
detail.title = title

# Assuming there are dialog in my.great.app.detail
detail.dialog.confirm.title = Done, saving?
detail.dialog.delete.message = Really?

# another (sub) view: my.great.app.detail.specialParts
detail.specialParts.title = very special
```

Works also flawless for multi component apps, if you prefix component name.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that is not what I want. A recent example is the postal code. Sometimes I have a combination of postal code and house number and sometimes just the postal code or just the house number. I don't want to use three seperate entries for that but rather "link" them to achieve this. This is maybe a small and trivial example, but there are far more comlex ones in my project